# VSTS - How add picklist (string) into the area beside State, Reason, Area and Iteration for the bug

Tags: azure-devops, picklist

Would you be so kind to advise on how to add picklist (string) into the area beside State, Reason, Area and Iteration for the bug, please?

Many thanks, in advance!

[Here is place where the picklist (string) field needs to be inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWc2T.png)

Comment: Do you clear it with Daniel's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add things to that region. The grey bar is a for system fields that are outside of your control.